# Removing sand out of a bagpack

Tags: cleaning

I think everyone knows it.
That trip to the beach, the bagpack with the stuff stored in.
And after it, it is impossible for anything stored withing not becoming sandy.

What is the best way for making the bagpack sandfree again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If the sack already has a grommet/eyelet, skip to 3
2. Make a small hole to the bottom of every compartment and secure the surrounding area from tearing apart with a [grommet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grommet).
3. Shower the inside of the bag with just water in your shower. This will flush out the stuff you do not want in there and the water together with the dirt can easily flow out. This will obviously also work without the grommet, but it then takes considerably longer to wash and dry.

This picture shows two such secured holes in rucksack bottom:

[image: Bottom holes in a rucksack]

Obviously, the material used for the bag cannot be prohibited from coming into contact with water. But for something taken to a beach this seems less of a concern.

Answer (score 6):

This actually is generic advice to thoroughly clean a bag. First you need to empty it of course.

1. Go outside.
   Garden? Anywhere that you can make a mess.
2. Turn the bag inside out; all compartments, one by one if necessary.
3. Shake
   This takes care of most of the grains
4. With a slightly wet rag, rub every single exposed area. Special attention is needed where the seams double up the fabric. Fold these first one way, then the other to get all.
5. If needed, tidy up the last bit with a vacuum cleaner to get the last nasty corners.

Fringe benefit: No more fluff!

Answer (score 3):

If you have some Blu-tac handy that you don't mind throwing away after use, you could roll some into a ball shape (then flatten it if you want a bigger surface area), then press the Blu-tac against the areas where the sand is stuck to lift and remove the sand.

I should mention it doesn't need to be Blu-tac - you can use the same principle with tape and other things that have weak/mild adhesive qualities.
I personally like Blu-tac for the ability to shape it to get it into all nooks and crannies